Does any Catholic Church in the West have image of Jesus in a squatting posture?
We read in Jn 8:2-6:

2 And early in the morning he came again into the temple, and all the people came to him, and sitting down he taught them  3 And the scribes and the Pharisees bring unto him a woman taken in adultery: and they set her in the midst  4 And said to him: Master, this woman was even now taken in adultery  5 Now Moses in the law commanded us to stone such a one. But what sayest thou 6 And this they said tempting him, that they might accuse him. But Jesus bowing himself down, wrote with his finger on the ground.

We generally see images of Jesus sitting on a raised platform say, a rock, to teach so that he is audible to maximum number of people. The Temple courtyard may have had benches of wood or stone. But in John 8:6 we see Jesus writing on the ground . The ground must have had a layer of loose sand where he wrote ( just as children writing their name on beach sand and watching the waves obliterating it ). That implies Jesus was squatting on the ground when the adulterous woman was brought to him for judgement. And the Jews address him as Teacher. In fact, there was a tradition in the Orient, of teachers squatting on the ground along with their disciples . Taking a cue from Jn 8, a few churches in India have images of Jesus squatting on the ground. My question is : Does any Catholic Church in the West have image of Jesus squatting on the ground in a posture of deep meditation.

"That implies Jesus was squatting on the ground" — What is "that" and how does it imply he was squatting? — Can't someone that is sitting on a bench lean forward and write on the ground?

Thanks, Ray Butterworth. Of course, he can . But the fact is: no film director or artist depicted Jesus doing so!

jesus writing on the ground - Google Search has a lot of images, none sitting on bench.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Here is a painting of the scene by Lucas Cranach the Elder that shows Jesus squatting as he writes on the ground (in Latin): QVI SINE PECCATO EST PRIMVS VOLLAT LAPIDEM ("Who is without sin throw the first stone"). This work is dated to 1521 and is thought to have originally been part of an altarpiece in a church in the German town of Halle. Would this information answer your question?

Thanks, njuffa. My question is not about image of the event itself, but about Jesus in isolation sitting on the ground in a posture of deep meditation.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan, I think sitting is different from squatting or stooping. If you're looking for images of Jesus sitting on the ground, it might be helpful to update the question.

Thanks Geremia, for editing the question. But I fear, you have edited the title in a manner beyond my expectation! One should not expect on an altar, the picture of an adulterous woman waiting for judgement before Jesus ( that would certainly divert the thoughts of Victorian age people !).  One can certainly expect images of Jesus in different postures including squatting in meditation. Please Google for Padmasana, a posture fit for deep meditation. You will see the intent of my question.

In English, the posture  is known as Lotus Pose of meditation.

Got it ! The Basilica of National Shrine of Immaculate Conception, Washington has on it fine, a beautiful image of Jesus in a squatting posture with hands raised . If you watch the Basilica TV Mass of 8 th September, you get to see the image when the Prayer of Spiritual Communion is displayed .

@KadalikattJosephSibichan, it's valid for answers to be provided by the same person who asked the original question. If you have done research and now have more information, why don't you develop it into a full answer with links, for the benefit of other readers.

Thanks Peter Kirkpatrick. I will, but let me first try to copy the link to the Church website or TV Mass.

The dome of Basilica of National Shrine of Immaculate Conception, Washington DC has a beautiful image of Jesus in a squatting posture with hands raised in prayer. Watch the Basilica TV Mass of 8 th September at
https://www.nationalshrine.org/ and you find the image along with the Prayer of Spiritual Communion after the Lamb of God Prayer.


Does any Catholic Church in the West have image of Jesus in a squatting posture?

This isn't the kind of answer you're looking for, but visit some Catalonian churches at Christmas time.  Their nativity scenes often traditionally include figurines known as Caganer - Wikipedia:

The exact origin of the Caganer is unknown, but the tradition has existed since at least the 18th century. According to the society Amics del Caganer (Friends of the Caganer), it is believed to have entered the nativity scene by the late 17th or early 18th century, during the Baroque period.

You can buy your own squatting Jesus:

(Popes, prime ministers, and most famous people are also available.)
Note that these squatting figurines are quite explicitly doing what people traditionally do when they squat, so you might prefer not to follow the image's link to the ad.
Why this became part of this region's Catholic tradition, I don't know, but this isn't a site for ridiculing other people's beliefs.

Ray Butterworth, if squatting evokes the thoughts of sitting on WC to someone, he/ she needs to travel beyond the West. Table and chair were most probably introduced to the Orient by the Western civilization. Many Indian languages have adapted the Portugese words for table and chair, implying that those items came to India with the Portugese. If you search for Yogic postures on Google, you will find the Lotus Pose of sitting on meditation , which is akin to squatting

@KadalikattJosephSibichan says "if squatting evokes the thoughts of sitting on WC to someone, he/ she needs to travel beyond the West" — and if it doesn't, stay away from Catalonia, or it will. E.g. see (or don't) The caganer in the 2011 official nativity scene in Barcelona's Plaça de Sant Jaume - Wikipedia.

Well, Ray Butterworth. Hope your next stopover is the Poop Hotel in Taiwan where you get poop -shaped dishes in WC- shaped plates !
